# Импорт csv в mysql

Tags: mysql

Хочу, чтобы при импорте из csv к каждой записи добавлялось поле "время добавления". Думал сделать по аналогии, как при обычном запросе и добавить поле в таблицу`field_createdAt` типа `DATETIME` значение по умолчанию `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` атрибут `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Но при импорте  в эти поля записываются вместо текущей даты `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Возможно как-то решить?

Comment: какой язык програмирования?

Comment: @L.Vadim php. разве это имеет значение? Я создаю таблицу в phpMyAdmin, c соответствующими колонками и импортирую файл туда.

Comment: Upd. Заполнил поле "Название столбцов" - все корректно пишет.

Answer (score 2):

> Думал сделать по аналогии, как при обычном запросе и добавить поле в таблицуfield_createdAt типа DATETIME значение по умолчанию CURRENT_TIMESTAMP атрибут on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Но при импорте в эти поля записываются вместо текущей даты 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

При импорте данных выполняется INSERT, а вовсе даже не UPDATE. Так что для поля требуется атрибут DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: этот атрибут присваивается по умолчанию, так? создал еще одну колонку,для теста, атрибут оставил пустым. все равно нули пишутся

Comment: Значит, что-то не так делаете. Небось импортируете без указания полей назначения? Ну тогда укажите требуемое значение явно: _LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt' INTO TABLE t1 (column1, column2) SET field_createdAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;_

Comment: Я импортирую  в phpMyAdmin, просто указав csv файл и выбираю формат CSV using LOAD DATA. Где можно прописать инструкции, которые вы указали?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Я импортирую только из консоли или запросами (что в общем одно и то же). Попробуйте вместо импорта средствами пхп-админа написать импортирующий запрос и через пхп-админа его выполнить, должно сработать как надо.

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin при создания поля дефаулт выставляете "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Comment: смысл в том, что если вручную добавлять что-то, то все нормально проставляется,при импорте из csv одни нули

Comment: можете написать что вы именно делаете? с примерами

Comment: phpMyAdmin -> Импорт -> Выберите файл  -> Выбираю -> Формат -> CSV using LOAD DATA -> Вперед.

Comment: едиственное что могу предложить это импортировать данные из CSV при помощи маленького скрипта на php